# I need to validate the form, the ajax should only work if the form validates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, parsley.js

I'm trying to validate the form. Its validating perfectly but the form is not submitting. In the console it says isValid() is not a function

I tried to give a condition that form validates

```js
$('#saveStudent').parsley();
```

```js
var addvalidation = new JustValidate('#saveStudent');

addvalidation.addField('#poster', [{
  rule: 'files',
  value: {
    files: {
      extensions: ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'],
      // maxSize: 25000,
      // minSize: 1000,
      types: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg'],
      // names: ['file1.jpeg', 'file2.png'],
    },
  },
  errorMessage: 'Only jpeg, jpg, png formats are supported.',
}, ]);
```

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#saveStudent', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  formData.append("save_student", true);
  
  if ($(this).parsley().isValid() && addvalidation.isValid()) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "save.php",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function (response) {
        $('#addMovie').show();
        $('#studentAddModal').modal('hide');
        $('#saveStudent')[0].`your text`reset();
        $('#myTable').load(location.href + " #myTable");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to call this method on the parsley instance, not on the jQuery-wrapped form. You just need to look at the example under https://parsleyjs.org/doc/#usage-configuration, to clearly see that.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP and AJAX, when you solely want to do something in JS? Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @CBroe Ok it's fine, parsley is now working fine. But i need to validate the uploaded file is in an image format or not. For that i used justvalidate library and the validations works fine its shows error messages. but the form is not submitting. How do i validate the justvalidate function just like the parsley did.

Comment: Can't spot any direct method in the docs that would give you a true/false result regarding validation, so perhaps you need to do it by using the `onSuccess` / `onFail` callbacks. Use those to set a flag, and have your AJAX code check on that flag, before it sends the request ...?